# Rearrange image grid upon browser resize?

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design, image-gallery

I have this pure css image grid that I wish to improve to make it more responsive to the browser window size. The columns and rows are currently fixed, which means that when you narrow the browser window the columns will get squashed, and the ideal thing in that scenario would be to switch over to fewer columns and more rows to minimize the image cropping (since the images are originally landscape oriented).

HTML structure:

```
<div class='padding'>
    <div class='column'>
        <div class='row'>
            <div class='thumb'>
                <div class='image' style='background-image:url(URL)'></div>
            </div>
            <div class='thumb'>
                <div class='image' style='background-image:url(URL)'></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='row'>
            <div class='thumb'>
                <div class='image' style='background-image:url(URL)'></div>
            </div>
            <div class='thumb'>
                <div class='image' style='background-image:url(URL)'></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='row'>
            <div class='thumb'>
                <div class='image' style='background-image:url(URL)'></div>
            </div>
            <div class='thumb'>
                <div class='image' style='background-image:url(URL)'></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='column'>
        <div class='row'>
            <div class='thumb'>
                <div class='image' style='background-image:url(URL)'></div>
            </div>
            <div class='thumb'>
                <div class='image' style='background-image:url(URL)'></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='row'>
            <div class='thumb'>
                <div class='image' style='background-image:url(URL)'></div>
            </div>
            <div class='thumb'>
                <div class='image' style='background-image:url(URL)'></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='row'>
            <div class='thumb'>
                <div class='image' style='background-image:url(URL)'></div>
            </div>
            <div class='thumb'>
                <div class='image' style='background-image:url(URL)'></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.padding {
    position:absolute;
    top:8px;
    right:8px;
    bottom:8px;
    left:8px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    -o-box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing:border-box;
}

.column {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    width:50%;
    height:100%;
}

.row {
    position:relative;
    display:flex;
    display:-webkit-flex;
    display:-o-flex;
    display:-moz-flex;
    display:-ms-flexbox;
    width:100%;
    height:calc(100%/3);
}

.thumb {
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    margin-top:8px;
    margin-right:8px;
    margin-left:8px;
    margin-bottom:8px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.image {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    right:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    left:0px;
    background-size:cover;
    background-position:center;
}
```

Here's a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xybosmzm/

I'm not sure where to start, but I guess I will need to use some javascript/jquery to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is called `media queries` you can read more about it [here](https://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/), it would look something like this when added:

```
.column {
    width:100%
}

@media screen and (min-width:470px) {
   .column {
     width:50%;
    }
}
```

The `@media` will make it so that when the screen is at least `470px` wide the column will be `50%` width of the screen otherwise it will take up the whole screen `width:100%`.

Here is a very simple [example](https://jsfiddle.net/xybosmzm/1/) try resizing the screen and you will that at one point the images will collapse from 4 in a row to 2

Comment: Wow, that's incredible! I had no idea it could be this simple. I will experiment a little bit with this. Could I use the same technique to resize the rows aswell to make the entire grid still fit into one page without a scroll?

Comment: Of course you can have as many media rules on different width's as you want, that means you can make it take up as much space as you need on higher width's.